# Site can't be reached after changing https to http

Tags: http, https

Tried changing website to from http to https for security and it works. Now, after changing back to http the site can't be reached but when I open it using private window/incognito it works. Can someone give an advice how can I view it using a normal browser?

**UPDATE:**
Issue can be fixed by clearing the cache. But what about users who'll view the website that doesn't know the clear cache thing?

Comment: More information is needed, please- URL, sample code, etc. example js fiddle project would be good.

Comment: @KenH. hey pal! I think this needs no code since all are working fine. Issue here is the site can only be viewed in a private window/incognito. Why vote down?

Comment: In case of firefox: try shift-reload.

Comment: @claudios - I took away the downvote. I just felt that putting a question with very little information to go on really was not a well-formed question. It is good that you got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Clearing your cache will do the trick.](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/) Also typing `http://yoursite.com` instead of `yoursite.com` will force modern browsers to use http instead of https.

Comment: Thanks! yes this will do the trick mate. But what about users who didn't know the clear cache thing?

Comment: Unless you revert your site to https and back again to http they wont need to. In this instance your browser remembers when yoursite.com was https and used that url instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you go back to http?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. I was also thinking of redirect stuff

Comment: Well, the site contains iframes that weren't hosted by our server and some of them are using http and it conflicts when I use https.

Comment: Unless you own https:// yoursite.com you will not be able to redirect users to any link.